# How to change menuitem tooltip text while tooltip active?

Tags: c#, winforms, menuitem

I have a first order menu item that is a chevron for toggling the state of a title panel.  The menu item has ToolTipText that I want to change while the tool tip window is still open (i.e. hover active).

Is there a way to make this happen ?

Code

```
    topMenuStrip.ShowItemToolTips = true;
    chevronMenuItem.ToolTipText = "Hide title";
    chevronMenuItem.Click += new System.EventHandler(titleToggle_Click);

    private void titleToggle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var mi = (ToolStripMenuItem)sender;

        if (titlePanel.Visible)
        {
            titlePanel.Visible = false;
            mi.ToolTipText = "Show title bar";                 // does not change while hover active
            mi.Image = Properties.Resources.chevron_expand;
        } 
        else
        {
            titlePanel.Visible = true;
            mi.ToolTipText = "Hide title bar";                 // does not change while hover active
            mi.Image = Properties.Resources.chevron_collapse;
        }
    }
```

Pictures

Third image is after the tooltip is rerendered after new hover (mouse leave chevron mouse enter chevron)

[image]

Comment: What is `titlePanel`? I could play with it if you prepare [mcve]. Otherwise try yourself: sending mouse commands (to force redraw), disabling/enabling that control with tooltip, refreshing or even manual tooltip show/hide.

Comment: `titlePanel` is the blurred content (in the top image) above the 'Host' input component.  The click handler might be able to get the tooltip window handle, but I don't know how to get that (I suppose it's auto created by the `topMenuStrip`)

Comment: Doing `mi.Visible=false;mi.Visible=true;` will update tooltip.

Comment: Sinatr, turning the menuitem visibility off and on did what was needed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft documentation, you must set the property **AutoToolTip = false** and the property **ShowItemToolTips = true**.

> ToolStripItem uses the Text property as the default source for the
>   ToolTip content. Set AutoToolTip to false to use ToolTipText as the
>   source for ToolTip content.
>
> To use this property, you must also set ShowItemToolTips to true.

Source: [ToolStripItem.AutoToolTip Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripitem.autotooltip?view=netframework-4.8)